# Can I say "I am out of breath because I have just been climbing the stairs"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idiomatic-language

I would like to know if I am correct about this. I have trouble climbing stairs because of health problems. I have just climbed stairs and I am out of breath.

Can I say: "I am out of breath because I have just been climbing the stairs"?

I am really proud of this fact and so I say: "I have climbed the stairs!"

Answer (score 2):

"I am out of breath because I have just been climbing the stairs" is correct.

However, "I am out of breath because I just climbed the stairs" is slightly more natural.

"I have climbed the stairs!" is also correct.

Comment: To add, I would say '*I just climbed the stairs!*' also demonstrates this but is colloquial because it misses the verb have. If you wished to say this phrase with correct grammar, '*I've just climbed the stairs!*' (the contraction sounding more natural) would work too.

Comment: 'I've just climbed the stairs' would be the most natural in British English.

Comment: @anouk: Don't think too much about the possibility that using the Perfect and/or Continuous might be "less natural". It's nothing to do with the basic construction in ***I am out of breath because...** [explanatory assertion]*. What's relevant here is that  "climbing the stairs" is usually thought of as a short duration (and hence, "likely to be completed") action. More generally, *I am out of breath because I have just been **running / jogging / weightlifting*** are much more likely than, say, ***...because I have just jogged / lifted weights*** (which to my ear are truly awful! :)

Comment: @embefær: It's not "colloquial" to use Simple Past *I just climbed the stairs* rather than the Perfect version *I **have** just climbed the stairs*. In some contexts the choice of verb form here might be governed by the intended meaning, but sometimes they're precisely equivalent (particularly given that the word ***just*** implies "recently", which itself implies "relevance to time of utterance" just as much as using Present Perfect does).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I am afraid I disagree. I am not sure which country you are from but the word just is often used with the past perfect tense with respect to this specific meaning. See the link [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/just) for further clarification. In this case, the remark would come off colloquial. Additionally, I stated it would sound natural with the contraction. Without, it may be correct but would come off rather less naturally.

Comment: I know perfectly what ***just*** means here (it would be perverse to assume the ***merely*** sense in OP's context). My point is that just because ***just = recently*** AND ***Present Perfect implies "relevance to time of utterance"*** doesn't mean there's some ***syntactic*** justification for including both features in the same utterance. And "colloquial" is not relevant to this issue.

Comment: Glad to know that is the case. The link in question does not provide just the definition pertaining to the sense of *just* being *merely* something. If you scroll down, it specifically refers to the usage of *just* employed here and addresses the point you make. To address your edit: I did not state colloquialisms were relevant to the issue which is precisely why I left a comment as an addendum rather than an answer. It may be useful to the person questioning to know this.

Comment: Yeah - I didn't actually follow your link before, but it's quite true that we *often* use Perfect forms with adverbial ***just = recently***. But this is simply a natural result of the semantics (both imply current relevance). So it's still just a stylistic choice, and there's nothing either more or less colloquial or formal about including both features in any given utterance.

Comment: I am not quite sure what the disagreement here is. Colloquialisms can also imply the same meaning as its formal equivalent. I am not denigrating the use of colloquialisms, if that is what appears to be the case. In this particular instance, the proper form would be '*I have just climbed the stairs*' or its contraction. You certainly could state the alternative and be understood, but it would be understood as a colloquialism. See [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/just-yet-still-and-already) also for further discussion on the notion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica Would you consider "I am out of breath because I have been climbing the stairs" correct? Or is it not idiomatic?

Comment: @Kate Bunting could you explain why the continuous is not natural? Climbing stairs is an activity with a duration that has a result now because you are out of breath

Comment: For the reason that FumbleFingers has already explained. Climbing the stairs is (normally) a brief action for the purpose of getting to the upper storey (unless you live in a high building without a lift!), not an ongoing activity like running or playing tennis. You certainly _can_ say "I've been climbing the stairs" if you have found it especially laborious, or have had to climb several flights - but it wouldn't be the _usual_ expression.

Comment: @embefær: I *think* my point of disagreement is you seem to be suggesting that Simple Past *I just climbed the stairs* is a "colloquial" alternative to Present Perfect *I **have** just climbed the stairs*. As I *[**have!?**]* pointed out earlier, that's just a stylistic choice - but it's nothing to do with ["colloquiality".](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22colloquiality%22)

Comment: @Kate Bunting would you consider washing dishes an ongoing activity?

Comment: As a British English speaker, I might say either _I've done the washing-up_ or _I've been doing the washing-up_!

Comment: @Kate Bunting without suggesting repetition in the latter sentence?

Comment: Yes - assuming there were a lot of dishes to wash all in one go!

Comment: @ Kate Bunting So if there were just some dishes to wash you wouldn't use the continuous? Let's say it took 5 minutes, would that be long enough to use the continuous?

Comment: @ FumbleFingers I have come across the sentence: "even when I'm sitting, I feel like I've been climbing stairs, catching my breath." Is this different because it doesn't say "the stairs"?